Python stacking multidimensional arrays from geotiff, grabbing index of max value of each pixel across stacks
I am fairly new to GeoSpatial coding and coding in general. I have roughly 100 geotiff files of the same region. I'd like to index each stack with the datetime, go pixel by pixel and solve for the max value (in my case velocity) across the stack of 100 geotiffs, and grab the corresponding datetime as day of year and plot spatially.
I'm mostly struggling with the stacking aspect.
I think I want my data structured where each slice looks like so:
y y y y ...
x z z z z
x z z z z
x z z z z
.
.
.
where x is the x coordinate, y is y coordinate, and z is velocity. Then each slice has a corresponding datetime and I want to look at the max z for each x y pair.
I'm also not sure what data structure I should use. Maybe pandas, or geopandas, or xarray.
Here is what I have so far. The way my data is saved I go through a list of subdirectories, grab geotiffs with the proper file ending, grab the date from the filename and convert to datetime. I then open the geotiff using rasterio and try to stack, which is where I get confused

import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import glob
import re
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def stack_geotiffs_and_find_max_index(directory, date_structure, filename_ending):
    # Get a list of all subdirectories
    subdirectories = next(os.walk(directory))[1]

    # Sort the list just in case the directories are not in the order you expect
    subdirectories.sort()

    # Process only the first subdirectory
    if subdirectories:
        subdir = subdirectories[3] #start with just 3 files

        # Find all files that end with the specified filename ending
        geotiff_files = glob.glob(f'{directory}{subdir}/*{filename_ending}')
 

        
        all_data = []

        for filepath in geotiff_files:
            filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
            match = re.search(date_structure, filename)
            if match:
                date_str = match.group(1)
                date_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d%b%y')
                formatted_date = date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                print(f"Processing file: {filename}, Date: {formatted_date}")

                with rasterio.open(filepath) as src:
                    band1 = src.read(1) #loads array of 650 x 800
                    all_data.append(band1)
     


        # Stack the arrays along a new dimension to create a 3D array
        data_3d = np.stack(all_data, axis=0)`


filename_ending = 'vv_v04.0_utm.tif'
date_structure = r'_(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2})_'
directory = '/hdd3/taku/satellite_velocity/TSX/Release2/Release2/Alaska-Taku/'
stack_geotiffs_and_find_max_index(directory, date_structure, filename_ending)


So explaining my array in line didn't go well. My array is 650 x 800 where all cells are velocity values for a particular x y pair. I want to stack these , find the maximum at each cell and grab the appropriate index which I want to be the datetime.
